# SQL query to retrieve Record from first table that has no matching subquery in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server and I'm struggling with a query to find all "In Service" Relays (TRELAY table) that have no "Active" Setting Requests (TREQUEST table).

TRELAY has a one to many relationship with TREQUEST.
The records in TREQUEST could have various statuses ('Not Ready', 'Pending', 'Active', 'Superseded').

I have tried subsqueries and joins (left/inner), but I can't get the query to return a distinct Relay record with no active setting request records. It's returning duplicate Relay records with all the duplicate Superseded Setting Requests.

I've tried to use the Not like 'Active', but I get multiple records of the Relay records.

```
T.S06 is the Status from the TRELAY table (string field)
R.S03 is the Setting Status from the TREQUEST tabe (string field)

SELECT T.ID, T.S06, R.S03 FROM TRELAY T
LEFT JOIN TREQUEST R ON R.RELAYID = T.ID AND  R.S03 NOT LIKE '%ACTIVE%'
WHERE T.S06 LIKE '%IN SERVICE%'
```

The result of the above query:

```
Relay ID || Status     || Setting Status
========================================
303      || In Service || Superseded
307      || In Service || Superseded
307      || In Service || Superseded
307      || In Service || Superseded
```

I appreciate any help you can provide. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks,
Joe C.

Comment: Your query would probably work if you just changed your `SELECT` to be a `SELECT DISTINCT`, so that it only grabs unique rows.

Comment: No luck with Distinct. It removed one of the 307 Relay ID, but still returned 2 of them.

Comment: I see. Then take a look at AdaTheDev's answer. In reality, it's usually best to avoid `LIKE` just for efficiency purposes. A `NOT EXISTS` may be the proper methodology here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into using `NOT EXISTS`, like this kind of approach:

```
SELECT x
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM Table2 t2 
    WHERE t2.Identifier = t1.Identifier AND...any other conditions...
)
```

Which is just saying, "find me all rows in table 1 where there is not a corresponding entry in Table2" - you just need to specify the exact conditions in that NOT EXISTS clause

Comment: I can get the subquery correct, at least I think so. It returns those records that are In Service and do not have an Active Setting Request:

Comment: SELECT * FROM TREQUEST R
INNER  JOIN TRELAY ON R.RELAYID = TRELAY.ID
WHERE R.RELAYID = TRELAY.ID AND R.S03 NOT LIKE '%ACTIVE%' AND TRELAY.S06 LIKE '%IN SERVICE%'

Comment: but when I encapsulate it inside the outer query, I can't get distinct relay records.  SELECT * FROM TRELAY
WHERE TRELAY.S06 LIKE '%IN SERVICE%' AND EXISTS
(
SELECT * FROM TREQUEST R
INNER  JOIN TRELAY ON R.RELAYID = TRELAY.ID
WHERE R.RELAYID = TRELAY.ID AND R.S03 NOT LIKE '%ACTIVE%' AND TRELAY.S06 LIKE '%IN SERVICE%'
)

Answer (score 0):

You are close, try inverting your logic.  Find all of your distinct Active RelayID's first.  Then Left Join them to your T.id and grab only the non-matches.

```
SELECT T.ID, T.S06 
FROM TRELAY as T
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Distinct RELAYID FROM TREQUEST WHERE S03 LIKE '%ACTIVE%') as R 
ON T.ID = R.RELAYID
WHERE T.S06 LIKE '%IN SERVICE%' AND R.RELAYID IS NULL;
```

The `R.RELAYID IS NULL` checks for a non-match.  Thus you get all your distinct T.ID's from your TRELAY table.

Should you need to go back and grab all the other "Setting Status" for each T.ID, you can link this set back to your TREQUEST table.

Hope that helps :)

*** EDIT ***

In Response to the comment:

`"When I use (Select T.ID, T.S06, TREQUEST.S03 FROM TRELAY AS T, TREQUEST) I get a multi-part identifier T.ID could not be bound. Do I need to do another join before the Left Join."`

Yes, you would do an `INNER JOIN` to the SQL I posted above.  Below is some code that would join your set of good T.ID's back to the TREQUEST table and pull out all the good S03 values associated with each unique T.ID.  I labeled your Good T.ID values as `GoodTID`.  And I labeled your new link to the TREQUEST table as `GoodR`.

```
SELECT GoodTID.ID, GoodTID.S06, GoodR.S03
FROM TREQUEST as GoodR
INNER JOIN

(SELECT T.ID, T.S06 
FROM TRELAY as T
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Distinct RELAYID FROM TREQUEST WHERE S03 LIKE '%ACTIVE%') as R 
ON T.ID = R.RELAYID
WHERE T.S06 LIKE '%IN SERVICE%' AND R.RELAYID IS NULL) as GoodTID

ON GoodTID.ID = GoodR.RELAYID;
```

This code will give you all RELAYID's and S03 codes that are `IN SERVICE` and not `ACTIVE`.

Let me know if you need more of an explanation.  Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thank you, that does help...I think. I need to break down the queries to ensure that it is retrieving only the records I want. One question, maybe you can help with. How do I join the TREQUEST table in the initial select statement. When I use (Select T.ID, T.S06, TREQUEST.S03 FROM TRELAY AS T, TREQUEST) I get a multi-part identifier T.ID could not be bound. Do I need to do another join before the Left Join.

Comment: I edited the above answer to to show you how to `INNER JOIN` the set of unique good T.ID's back to the TREQUEST table and show all your 'In Service' and not 'Active' S03 codes.

Comment: Thank you. I want to do more testing to make sure it's working correctly, but all appears to be in order. I really appreciate the help. I owe you a virtual beer. :)